# Instance Groups do not Initate when Existing Disk Attached

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gce-instance-group

First of all this setup is for a proof of concept. The existing disk is ext4 formatted. A total of 4 instance groups created to troubleshoot. The status of 3/4 instance groups has been "Group is Resizing," some for over 4 hours. A minimum-2 and max-5 instances set between all groups for consistency. Only stateless Instance group 3 works, see below for further group details.

Edit: Each instance group is based on an instance template

**Stateless Instance group 1:**

f1-micro -> Ubuntu 18.04 -> 10GB Boot -> with Startup script -> Attached Existing Disk (20GB) SSD Persistent Disk

**Stateless Instance group 2:**

f1-micro -> Ubuntu 18.04 -> 10GB Boot -> noStartup script -> Attached Existing Disk (20GB) SSD Persistent Disk

**Stateless Instance group 3:** *Only one that works*

f1-micro -> Ubuntu 18.04 -> 10GB Boot -> noStartup script -> No Additional Disks

**Stateful Instance group 1:**

f1-micro -> Ubuntu 18.04 -> 10GB Boot -> noStartup script -> (Stateful) Existing Disk (20GB) SSD Persistent Disk

Comment: What do the logs tell you?

Comment: What errors do you see? We are not able to help you without more detail.

Comment: After looking through this a number of times, it seems to be linked to attaching a (single) disk into multiple VMs. 

Without using instance groups, the 2nd option was to simply create 2 similar VMs with Zonal persistent Disks (1 R+W) and (1 R) on the 2nd VM, however cloud console will not allow this configuration.